# WPF Add a button with image and style dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

My objective is as follows: I want to drag drop a file to my WPF window and it should create a button with the icon image at run time.

Currently my code simply creates a button without any image in it. Im new to WPF so please go easy on me!

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AttachedProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public static void SetImageSource(DependencyObject d, ImageSource source)
{
    d.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, source);
}


private Bitmap GetIconImageFromFile(String filename)
{
    Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename).ToBitmap();
    bmp.Save("test.bmp");
    return bmp;
}

private BitmapImage GetBitmapImageFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
        memory.Position = 0;
        memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
    }

    return bitmapImage;
}

private void Window_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) == true)
    {
        String[] fileNames = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);


        foreach (String fileName in fileNames)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("WindowDrop " + fileName);

            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Width = 100;
            newButton.Height = 50;
            //newButton.Template = (ControlTemplate)TryFindResource("btemp2");
            Bitmap bmp = GetIconImageFromFile(fileName);
            BitmapSource src = GetBitmapImageFromBitmap(bmp);
            AttachedProperties.SetImageSource(newButton,src);
            stack.Children.Add(newButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code as follows , I create Image instance and set it as button content. Please try this.

```
foreach (String fileName in fileNames)
{
    MessageBox.Show("WindowDrop " + fileName);

    Button newButton = new Button();
    newButton.Width = 100;
    newButton.Height = 50;


    //Craete the Image isntance and set the image to be dispalyed
    Image ButtonPicture = new Image();
    ButtonPicture.BaseUri = fileName;

    //Set it to the button content
    newButton.Content = ButtonPicture;

    AttachedProperties.SetImageSource(newButton,src);
    stack.Children.Add(newButton);
}
```

Comment: Hi it works. Now i want to add a style to the button. This style simply has a Image in a Border. I want to apply this style to the button. Then, I want to make the image's source to be my bitmap